# Send Data to external application

Tags: api, leads, appexchange, connected-apps

[image: I'd appreciate some help understanding how to solve this]

In this scenario I'm sending data to externel application.I tried with test records , and parsing parameters , both are working fine. but I need to set Apex trigger to when new lead inserted, need to execute this function. but we can't use apex trigger directly because this is a callout. other than that I already try the queueable apex but its also not doing the thing , how Can I solve this
-- I'd appreciate some help understanding how to solve this